# Apache Ignite does not distribute an executing closure to a newly spawned node in the compute grid

Tags: ignite

**Apache Ignite Version is: 2.1.0**

I am using the default configuration for client & servers. The following is the client configuration. The server configuration does not have the "clientMode" property.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <bean abstract="true" id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <!-- Set to true to enable distributed class loading for examples, default is false. -->
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="clientMode" value="true"/>

        <!-- Enable task execution events for examples. -->
        <property name="includeEventTypes">
            <list>
                <!--Task execution events-->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_STARTED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FINISHED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FAILED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_TIMEDOUT"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_SESSION_ATTR_SET"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_REDUCED"/>

                <!--Cache events -->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_READ"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED"/>

            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <!--
                        Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                        instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                        to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                    -->
                    <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                    <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
                    <!-- <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">  -->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                <value>xxx.1y4.1zz.91:47500..47509</value>
                                <value>xxx.1y4.1zz.92:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The closure gets executed over the server nodes in the grid as expected.

When we add a new node by executing the below command to the grid during the execution of closure

**.\ignite.bat ..\examples\config\example-ignite.xml**

The existing nodes acknowledge the addition of the new node in the grid but the closure is not distributed to the newly added node.

Is there any configuration available to enable execution of closure to a node added during the execution of the closure?

**Edit 1:**

Below is the IgniteClosure implementation class:

```
public class SimpleInterestClosure implements IgniteClosure<SimpleInterestParam, AccruedSimpleInterest> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5542687183747797356L;

private static final BigInteger HUNDRED = new BigInteger("100".getBytes());

private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("SimpleInterestClosure");

@Override
public AccruedSimpleInterest apply(SimpleInterestParam e) {
    BigInteger si = e.getPrincipal().multiply(new BigInteger(e.getDurationInYears().toString().getBytes())).
            multiply(new BigInteger(e.getInterestRate().toString().getBytes())).divide(SimpleInterestClosure.HUNDRED);
    log.info("Calculated SI for id=" + e.getId());
    return  new AccruedSimpleInterest(e, si);
}

}
```

**Edit 2:**

Below is the method which invokes the IgniteClosure implementation

```
public void method() throws IgniteException, IOException {

    Factory<SimpleInterestClosure> siClosureFactory = FactoryBuilder.singletonfactoryOf( new SimpleInterestClosure());

    ClassPathResource ress = new ClassPathResource("example-ignite.xml");
    File file = new File(ress.getPath());

    try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(file.getPath())) {
        log.info("Started Ignite Cluster");
        IgniteFuture<Collection<AccruedSimpleInterest>> igniteFuture = ignite.compute()
                .applyAsync(siClosureFactory.create(), createParamCollection());
        Collection<AccruedSimpleInterest> res = igniteFuture.get();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give more details on the use case? Are you doing a broadcast? Why do you need this closure to be executed on the new node?

Comment: @ValentinKulichenko - I am not doing a broadcast. The grid is being used by several closure implementations. In case there is need to have a node available for waiting closures or in another case if a node dies and we spawn a new node to compensate for the failed node.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Can you describe scenario step by step? Most likely you're looking for job stealing: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/load-balancing#job-stealing. In your case it can require this fix though: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-1267

Comment: @ValentinKulichenko - I am not able to edit my earlier comment, so adding a new one. I am not doing a broadcast. The grid is being used by several closure implementations and my use case is to have additional nodes available for already running closures. 

I believe the info you gave in your last comment will help.

Comment: OK, added this as reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you're looking for job stealing: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/load-balancing#job-stealing

Although it currently has a bug that may be an issue in this particular case: http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-1267

Comment: Hello @valentin

I am facing some issues in enabling job stealing. I have posted another question. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58948793/job-stealing-configuration-not-working-in-apache-ignite